# Yes or no input else if trouble

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, input

I have an else if statement that will ask the user if they would like to scale the a number. If the answer is No then I want the scaler to be 0, while if the answer is yes, I would like the user to input the scaler. Every time I run the yes scaler, it still detects that the scaler is 0 and never lets the user input a number. Any suggestions?

Here is my code and output:

```
print ("Do you want to scale the price, Yes or No?")
answer = input("")

if answer == 'no' or 'No':
    scale = 0
elif answer == 'yes' or 'Yes':
    print("How much would you like to scale it by?")
    scale = float(input ())


print (scale)

output:

Do you want to scale the price, Yes or No?
 Yes
0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you break apart your first `if` statement, you can rewrite what you have as:

```
if (answer=='no') or 'No':
```

Because `'No'` is a non-empty string, it will always evaluate to `True`.  So this block will always be executed.

To fix this, use `in`:

```
if answer in ('no', 'No'):
    scale = 0
elif answer in ('yes', 'Yes'):
    print("How much would you like to scale it by?")
    scale = float(input ())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the answer for both "no" and "No", similarly for both "yes" and "Yes".

Make the following changes in your code:

```
print ("Do you want to scale the price, Yes or No?")
answer = input("")

if answer == 'no' or answer == 'No':
    scale = 0
elif answer == 'yes' or answer == 'Yes':
    print("How much would you like to scale it by?")
    scale = float(input ())


print (scale)
```

Output:

```
Do you want to scale the price, Yes or No?
yes
How much would you like to scale it by?
5
5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix:

```
print ("Do you want to scale the price, Yes or No?")
answer = input()

if answer == 'no' or answer=='No':
    scale = 0
elif answer == 'yes' or answer== 'Yes':
    print("How much would you like to scale it by?")
    scale = float(input ())


print (scale)
```

'no' or 'No' would result in yes and that would be compared with answer, so that would always be true. So change it by two statement with or

Answer (score -2):

Try this:
`if answer == 'no' or answer == 'No':`
...
`elif answer == 'yes' or answer == 'Yes':`

Comment: Re [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75855797/5211833) you just voted to close as spam: please don't do that. Instead, simply use a red spam flag (top flag in the flag dialogue). That way, the post is deleted quickly (once it reaches 6 red flags) and trains the automated spam blocking system. Closing a question for being spam does neither of these things and keeps it visible to everyone. Thus, please do flag such posts as spam in the future.